# python - How do I update the screen (canvas) of a Tkinter window just with using function

Tags: python, canvas

I have searched and haven't found the answer. 
How could I show given numbers from the user in the canvas by updating the windows after each number and with using functions not classes? 
This is my code.

```
# Import the module
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# intialize globals
value = 98

# Define event handler functions
canvas = Canvas(width=100, height=100, bg='blue')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

def enter():
    global value
    value = float(Enter_number.get())
    canvas.create_text(20, 20, text=str(value))

# Register event handlers
Enter_number = Entry(root)
Enter_number.pack()
Button(root,text="Get Number",command = enter).pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

# Start frame and timers
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works on my machine. I enter "42" and press the button, and it shows "42.0" on the canvas.

Comment: if you enter the other number, It is Displayed on the previous number. that is problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`canvas.delete`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) to remove previously drawn elements from a canvas.

```
value = float(Enter_number.get())
canvas.delete(ALL)
canvas.create_text(20, 20, text=str(value))
```

Alternatively, you could keep track of the item id given by `create_text`, and change the text of the existing text item using [`canvas.itemconfig`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method), instead of creating a new one. Normally I'd keep a reference to the id in a class, but since you've forbidden that, you can use a global.

```
text_id = None

def enter():
    global value
    global text_id
    value = float(Enter_number.get())
    if text_id == None:
        text_id = canvas.create_text(20, 20, text=str(value))
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text=str(value))
```